# Is there a turn-based game service (like GKTurnBasedMatch on iOS) for desktops?

Tags: server, turn-based

Game Center's GKTurnBasedMatch seems to provide a pretty robust service for handling turn-based games, and OpenFeint appears to have something similar. The problem is, I'd like something like this for the desktop. I was thinking of rolling my own REST-based service on Rails, but after looking at the GameKit documentation, I realized it would take longer than I'd like to make it solid. I don't suppose something like this already exists that I missed in my searches?

Comment: Good question. It's kinda strange that frameworks like OpenFeint or plus+ focus on mobile devices only. Looking at the recent decisions made by Apple, I guess GameCenter isn't far from being available for Lion.. but that's just a guess.

Answer (score 3):

Not really, I think you would want to program all the networking stuff yourself, I would make turn based stuff like so:

```
    Server::ProcessNetwork(ClientID p_ID, EOPCODE p_In){
    switch(p_In)
    {
        case OP_NOACTION: // No action would be like a heartbeat to tell the server its still there.
        //user is still waiting
        break;

        case OP_ENDTURN:
        EndTurn(p_ID);
        break;

        case OP_SOMEACTION:
        //perform some action
        break;

        case OP_DISCONNECT:
        // User is disconnecting
        Disconect(p_ID);
        break;
    }
```

Again, just an idea I thought you could use, hope it helps.